# node.js: using process.env to store whole app configuration

Tags: node.js, config, configuration-files

Well maybe a little bit strange and basic question but..

As usual in my application I have some configurations parameters specific for current environment like dbs, paths, keys, logins etc.

There is an access to process.env object that may contain any number of string properties, so why not use it for storing all the config information and use it across the application?

I've seen people are using some custom config files or some modules like nconf (https://github.com/flatiron/nconf).

nconf seems to be very robust,  but I don't really see where I may use its power, as I just need to be able init some shared parameters and use it in different app's modules.

So the question is init and store configuration parameters in process.env and use across all application code just in sake of simplicity?

Comment: I usually create different config files and pass the name of the config file via an environment variable into the node.js app.

Comment: Me too. In config files (that are .js) I just set process.env properties. So, question is about where to store and how to access config parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use [global](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global), adding a new variable into the global scope. Just be careful with it ;-)

Comment: That is too interesting why not use global for storing config. Why should one be careful with it?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR it's globally available and could be overwritten somewhere.